# Troubles with showing axis after saving in EPS

Tags: image, save, eps-format

I'm trying to save a picture in EPS and then to put it into my LaTeX document. But when I put it the left axis is not shown. How do I fix it? 
(look at the screens)
If I save the image in JPG, there're no any problems
[image: the latex result]
[image: the wolfram code]

Comment: Please provide the code and definitions that generated those pictures in a copy/pasteable format in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I included my "EPS" mathematica output in latex like

```
 \includegraphics{plot.eps}
```

Try to save your Latex document as .pdf.

Open this document and zoom into "page width". 
Then the axes should be shown properly.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine with other formats. Just it's strange that it works like this with .eps @stef